# Returning a JSON object from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, function, object

Trying to parse through some livestream JSON data and see if an event has a specific tag.
If it doesn't then I'll use that data to output values, etc.

For whatever reason, `upcoming_event` isn't being assigned the event object (which is the return value of the `findPublicEvent` function.

The console.log of the event object works fine - but returning it doesn't work :/

```
// get our NLC data from livestream.
// -> note: need the '?callback=?' to convert to JSONP for cross-domain usage
var $uri = 'http://api.new.livestream.com/accounts/newlifechurchtv/?callback=?';
$.getJSON($uri, function(data) {
    parseNLCData(data);
});

parseNLCData = function(nlc_data){
  // set our variable to the return first event
  // nlc_data.upcoming_events.data is a json array of events
  window.upcoming_event = findPublicEvent(nlc_data.upcoming_events.data);
}

// should return single public event
function findPublicEvent (all_events) {
  // if we have events
  if (all_events) {
    // loop through events to find public event
    $.each(all_events, function(index,value){
      // get all the tags, remove whitespace, and put into array
      var $tags = value.tags.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase().split(',');
      // check for privacy.
      var $privacy = $.inArray('private', $tags);
      if ($privacy === -1) {
        // if the event isn't private -> return it!
        console.log(value);
        return value;
      }
    });
   // otherwise .... ->
   } else {
    // we don't have events, sooo, no dice.
    return false;
   }

 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findPublicEvent` isn't returning it. The anonymous function you pass to `each` is returning it.

Since it is the return value of `findPublicEvent` that you are capturing, you can't see it.

1. Define a variable in the scope of `findPublicEvent`
2. Assign a value to it from inside your anonymous function (using a regular assignment, not a return)
3. Return that variable from `findPublicEvent`